# Creating Javafx jar files

Tags: javafx, deployment, jar

I have a a Javafx (fxml) application that I need to deploy as a jar file (using Intellij). However, this apparently cannot be done in later versions of Javafx. You need third party tools to create Javafx jars. The problem: I cannot seem to get any sources on-line that will list downloadable tools to create jars from Javafx apps. Any recommendations will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which version java are you using?

Comment: java version 15.0.1

Comment: Note: On the advice of the JetBrains help desk, I found the solution on this website: https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX

Answer (score 0):

To make your life easier, you can use this awesome plugin [Java Packager](https://github.com/fvarrui/JavaPackager) that can create jar, .exe, and executable installer for Mac, Windows & Linux with just 1 command line `mvn package`

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely try it.